# Convert dataframe to dictionary using values as keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'value': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key': ['key1', 'key1', 'key2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to convert it to a dictionary in the form

```
{
'key1': ['value1', 'value2'], 
'key2': ['value2']
}
```

I tried `df.to_dict()`, but the entries are not formed properly in the dictionary. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('key')['value'].agg(list).to_dict()
# run time
# 897 µs ± 50.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Or:

```
{k:list(x) for k,x in df.groupby('key')['value']}
# run time
# 376 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

output:

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3']}
```